# How can I delete local mail on mac and stop terminal saying "You have mail."

Tags: macos, terminal, email

I set up a wayward cron task and accidentally sent a lot of emails to the Mac's local mail server (when opening terminal, it says "You have mail."), they're all junk and I want to remove them. What is the best way to do so?

I have considered a couple of approaches, but I don't want to risk breaking something. Here are those 2 approaches:

1. simply deleting the file [`/var/mail/$USER`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85090/302720)
2. [This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5465204) approach:

> Go to the Finder, hold down the Option key and click the Go menu. You'll see a Library folder in the list. Click that. (You can only see it when you hold down the Option key.)
> Within, there's a Mail folder, then v2, then subfolders for accounts. Your old account folder may be there, although I've always experienced it being deleted when an account is removed.

I'm a little unsure about this because I don't see `V2`, but instead `V8`, and I have no idea what those files are:

[image]

So I am unsure of what to do. The goal is to safely remove any potential junk from my computer, and stop the "You have mail." message from appearing when I start the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `/var/mail/$USER`. The other option would remove the actual mails you see in Mail.App, this is for sure not what you want.

If you keep getting mails in Terminal, run `less /var/mail/$USER` to see which processes are sending them.